# Dealing with data from MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib

I'm a quite new to both Python and MySQL so I hope someone could help me a bit.

Here is what I'm having trouble with. I have to use Python to do some analysis and visualization with data fetched from MySQL. For example, it might be a simple time series. So when I use `fetchall()`, I will get a tuple of the form, say,

```
(("20140101",112233),("20140102",445566),....).
```

I feel like dealing with tuple directly may not be the best way to do data analysis and I don't even know how to do it. So my question is what is the most efficient way (if there is) to contain the data in Python so that I could use matplotlib to plot the data and do some statistical analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pandas would be a good fit for this:

```
import pandas
cur = db.cursor()
nf = pandas.io.sql.read_frame("select * from tablename limit 50;", db)
```

Will put your data into a data frame (native type in pandas) and you can treat data in rows/columns and pandas integrates well with matplotlib